# Test whether a sample (which is a 1D array of values) comes from a population (2D array of values)

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, p-value, goodness-of-fit

I'm taking samples in such a way that I record multiple discrete values for each sample. Given an instance of a sample, is there any way to test if this sample appears to "fit" the population of other samples I've taken? I think this is similar to the idea of "goodness-of-fit", but it's a slightly different question/format. Any help on methods/algorithms to look into would be greatly appreciated.

To give some information on my data, I have counts for various "features" for each sample in my dataset. So each sample is a vector of integers, and so my whole population is a 2D vector. I want to see if a new sample appears statistically similar to the other samples that we've seen in the past.

By "fit," I mean, how close is the given sample compared to the other samples in this population? Could it be a part of this population? Or, how representative is it of what's typically seen in this population?

Comment: This may be too vague to be answerable.  Could you include more information about your data and especially about what you mean by "fit"?  To make progress we will need to quantify the "fit."

Comment: Thanks @whuber , I gave some additional information to hopefully make my question more understandable.

Comment: That's a start.  Could you tell us how long these vectors are and what the typical count values tend to be?